# DropDownList control does not works in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I am using DropDownList control .net 3.5 in my page and it works fine in IE, Firefox but does not work in google chrome. When i click on DropdownList control for selecting values, nothing happened in google chrome.

Can anybody explain why ?

Answer (score 1):

add 
**style="position:relative; z-index:auto;"**
to your dropdownlist in your asp.net page then it will work.